# Why do the BPO henchmen wear hazmat gear?

Tags: plot-explanation, sense8

In the first season of Netflix's Sense8, one can see personnel of the Biologic Preservation Organization wear oxygen tanks and face masks several times when engaging *sensates*.

As *sensates* don't seem to spread any biological or chemical hazards this strikes me as odd.
Is any reason given for this choice of equipment?

Answer (score 3):

**In universe explanation :**

*Sensates* have **not yet been proven to be harmless**. Perhaps they irradiate some sort of factor that turn other people into *sensates* as well ? Perhaps they carry a disease that is inoffensive to most (healthy carrier) but might kill some ?

As long as you haven't captured them and studied them you cannot be sure it is safe to be around them.

**Out of universe explanation :**

Hazmat gear just looks **scary**. If you want to make scary henchmen but still want them to be related to scientific purpose, the Hazmat gear fits both.

It also brings back memories from SF alien movies where they usually wear this kind of gear to approach aliens. (Emphasize on the abnormal/otherworldly side of the *sensates*)